# Why doesn't limestone layer on house walls (now dust) flow off when it rains due to dissolved carbon dioxide?

Tags: solubility, environmental-chemistry

What happens  to the limestone layer formed on house walls after whitewashing?
Why does it not flow off when it rains, as rainwater contains $\ce{CO2}$?
That will covert $\ce{CaCO3}$ into calcium bicarbonate that is soluble in water?

When  $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ is applied on a wall for whitewashing it reacts with atmospheric  $\ce{CO2}$ to give $\ce{CaCO3}$ (and a shiny appearence), but we also learned that, when we pass  $\ce{CO2}$ from aqueous solution,  $\ce{CaCO3}$ will change into sodium hydrogen carbonate ($\ce{CaHCO3}$) that is soluble in water, so we know $\ce{CaCO3}$ was present on wall (from above discussion), then supposing it rains that will also contain dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ obviously. So why doesn't this dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ in rainwater react with $\ce{CaCO3}$ of the wall and wash off by forming $\ce{CaHCO3}$ (soluble in water)?

Comment: Please check spelling and grammar before posting. It is difficult to understand what you mean otherwise and as a  result your post is apt to get less attention.

Comment: It is not a question of if, but how fast. The answer is very slowly.

Answer (score 2):

When applying a solution or an emulsion of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ on a wall, this substance gets deposited on the wall. But it will soon be transformed into calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$ which is insoluble in water. Now the rain may fall down against this wall. And this water contains a small amount of dissolved $\ce{CO2}$. So, of course, this $\ce{CO2}$ can react with the deposit of $\ce{CaCO3}$ according to the reaction : $$\ce{CaCO3 + CO2 + H2O -> Ca^{2+} + 2 HCO3^-}$$ producing a solution containing the ions $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ and $\ce{HCO3^-}$ as if it was a solution of the non existant $\ce{Ca(HCO3)_2}$.

If I read correctly your message, you are surprised that this reaction does not dissolve your deposit when it's raining. This is a good question. But you should realize that rain drops contain an extremely low amount of $\ce{CO2}$, maximum $1$ gram per liter. Each rain drop contains less than $0.01$ milligram $\ce{CO2}$. And the rain does not stay a long time on the wall. Furthermore, the reaction is not immediate. So the rain does dissolve $\ce{CaCO3}$ on your wall, but at such a low rate that it will take years and even centuries for the deposit to be eliminated by rain washing.